# Unable to install a previous version of Sphinx

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm trying to install a previous version of Sphinx i.e. `2.1.7`, and here is what I did to accomplish the goal:

1. Downloaded the old version from [this](http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads/sphinx-2.1.7-release-osx10.9-x86_64.tar.gz/thankyou.html) link, and extracted it at Desktop.
2. Entered in to the project directory, and `cd ~/Downloads/sphinx/sphinx/api/libsphinxclient`, and did `./configure --with-mysql`
3. Did `make` & `make install`.
4. Included `~/Downloads/sphinx/sphinx/bin` in `$PATH`, and wrote this functionality in .bash_profile.
5. Now, when I do `searchd --version`, it gives me the following error:

   dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/mysql55/mysql/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
     Referenced from: /Users/arslanali/Downloads/sphinx/bin/searchd
     Reason: image not found
   Trace/BPT trap: 5

Now, I've tried every solution to get rid of this error, but unable to get it resolved.

**Edit:**

I'd had the latest version of MySQL, and when returned to previous, the mentioned error went away, but now I'm facing the following error each time I do: `searchd --version`,

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libexpat.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/arslanali/Downloads/sphinx/bin/searchd
  Reason: Incompatible library version: searchd requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libexpat.1.dylib provides version 7.0.0
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Comment: Why are you cd'ing ingo the libsphinxclient? thats just building the client. Try `cd ~/Downloads/sphinx/sphinx/`   - also with `make install` means shouldnt need to referenec searchd in where special, as long as root, will install sphinx in global position.

Comment: In root path, if I do `./configure --with-mysql`, it says: `-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory`

Comment: Ah, the tar.gz you've linked to is the binary release. Its already compiled (which is why you have a searchd command despite not compiling). To compile it yourself, you need the source release, rather than a binary release. http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads/sphinx-2.1.7-release.tar.gz/thankyou.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing same issue, I was trying to compile the binary release, Its already compiled (which is why you have a searchd command despite not compiling). 
So we need source of thinking sphinx in order to compile it successfully.

1) Downloaded source from
http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads/sphinx-2.1.7-release.tar.gz/thankyou.html

2) Un-zip downloaded file.

3) Cd into unzipped folder.

4) Run following commands.

```
./configure --with-mysql
make 
make install
```

5) Done :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib
/usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib /usr/local/bin/indexer
```

you might have to change the paths to match yours.

Comment: It says: `can't open file: /usr/local/bin/indexer (No such file or directory)`

Comment: I gave it my own path as well: the path to where I've downloaded Sphinx. With that, it doesn't give me any warning or error, but after doing this, when I again do: `searchd --version`, it again gives me the same error: `dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/mysql55/mysql/libmysqlclient.18.dylib`